I am stuck on something in Training Manual
I am a newcomer to QGIS and following up Training Manual item by item so that I can get a detailed overview of what QGIS is.
Just now I was reading section 4.2.2. ★★☆ Follow Along: Creating the dynamic header (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/dynamic_layout.html) and I was stuck on that part. The problem here is that the manual says:


Again, go to the Item Properties and open the Position and Size section. Using "Data defined" override, choose the sw_layout_margin variable for X as well as for Y.


The problem here is that we have defined "sw_layout_margin variable" at the beginning of this section for the Map item. But you cannot choose the sw_layout_margin variable for X as well as for Y unless you do not define here AGAIN for the "header" item. And this is also valid for the upcoming part of the tutorial for adding vertical and horizontal lines. As far as I see, you cannot use the variable defined for an item for another item.
Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

